# Is there any solution for retrieving large files from database with NestJs

Tags: nestjs, body-parser

My NestJS app was having issues of too large file uploading and it came to be BodyParser would have been the solution  then i used bodyparser to set limit to 50mb and it works! until now the issue started again after I uploaded many files and wanna get it. I have tried to set it to 1gb 500mb and the parameterLimit: from 50000 to 500000  but still the issue is there. I can still upload files but i can’t fetch it. and that should be normal,  since im not uploading many files for one Post request but to fetch it all, i have to query all of it at the sometime to an array of data, so the requested data become large and that is where NestJS throw an error of to large. Actually i don’t know where to set the outgoing data size limits.

Here my controller

```
@Get()
    async fetchAll(): Promise<Intro[]> {
    return await this.sejourService.findAll();
}
```

And here my service

```
async findAll(): Promise <Intro[]> {
    return await this.introModel.find();
 }
```

And in my main
app.use(bodyParser.json({limi: '900mb'}));
app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({ limit: '900mb', extended: true})

Any help will be welcomed

Comment: Wouldn't this be something due to `multer`, not `body-parser`, because it's a file upload?

Comment: Why would you send it over base64 and not use  something like multipart and then base64 it inside your server? That seems like extra stress on the client than necessary

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what issues you were running into with the `FileInterceptor`, but it can absolutely handle gig+ size files. A simple endpoint like

```js
@Controller()
export class AppController {

  @Post('file')
  @UseInterceptors(FileInterceptor('file'))
  uploadFile(@UploadedFile() file: Express.Multer.File) {
    console.log(file);
    return { status: 'ok' };
  }
}
```

is all that's needed to accept the incoming file. I tested this using curl like

```sh
 curl http://localhost:3000/file -F 'file=@~/Downloads/1GB.zip'
{"status":"ok"}
```

And got the following log in my server

```
{
  fieldname: 'file',
  originalname: '1GB.zip',
  encoding: '7bit',
  mimetype: 'application/octet-stream',
  buffer: <Buffer ff da 18 9f 40 8d 04 a1 31 5f 6c 15 62 8b 6c 56 4f e7 84 d8 f3 01 4a 78 b7 36 9e ff b9 a8 f8 a7 06 f9 5a 89 57 a3 39 0f 0b 90 dc 30 8f 85 46 b1 ce 41 ... 1073741774 more bytes>,
  size: 1073741824
}
```

As you can see, the size is there, the mimetype is set, and the `buffer` property now has all the data encoded in the file.

---

I was not able to create a string of such size to send through curl or postman without killing the process running the applications/commands, but if for whatever reason the above is not doable for you, the following should be fine in the `main.ts`

```js
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import * as bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule, { bodyParser: false });
  app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ limit: '2gb', extended: true }));
  app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: '2gb' });
  await app.listen(3000);
}
bootstrap();
```

---

To retrieve the large file, all that's needed is something like the `StreamableFile` API from Nest and returning the read stream like so:

```js
 @Get(':file')
  getFile(@Param('file') fileName) {
    return new StreamableFile(
      createReadStream(join(process.cwd(), 'uploads', fileName)),
    );
  }
```

This assumes you've uploaded the files to `./uploads` and you have the name available. Tested, and it works fine.

Comment: Your entire question was about bodyParser which is a request side middleware. It doesn't effect what's returned from the server

Comment: It's not really clearly explained at all. You mention body parser, which as I mentioned, is a middleware for incoming requests, not outgoing. You briefly mention you "wanna get it" referring to retrieving the file (which I admit, I missed). But file retrieval has **nothing** to do with the body parser middleware. What would be more helpful is to show how you're trying to set up the file retrieval in the first place. The solution I've provided above works.

Comment: Definitely the problem was not from NestJS neither from my code, the problem was from where i hosted the app!